# Changing font-family of react-stripe-elements

Tags: css, reactjs, stripe-payments

So I'm integrating Stripe elements into my React app and I'm having a time trying to change the font of the elements. I've tried passing the style using a style const but that doesn't change anything

```
const style = {
  base: {
    fontFamily: '"Poppins", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol"'
  }
}

<CardNumberElement style={style} className="form-control" id="cardNumber" placeholder="XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX" type="text" />
```

I've tried using the code in this GitHub issue: https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/issues/179

I've tried this: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/change-css-for-checkout-form/

I've tried just using plain inline styling. Please anyone who's had to deal with this help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe provides a `<Elements>` component which you need to use to wrap all the stripe elements and provide the following fonts object as props to `Elements`:

```
<Elements
  options={{
    fonts: [
      {
        cssSrc:
          'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo&display=swap'
      }
    ]
  }}
>
  <MyComponent />
</Elements>
```